# How do I change the default number of products in pagination on Spartacus product listing page?

Tags: pagination, spartacus-storefront

Pagination on the Spartacus Product Listing Page also pagines 10 products by default.

I want PLP to have 24 products in paging. I customized the OCC / search service in Java and I see pageSize = 12 under Network in the browser, but the page is still pagination with 10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZg0T.png)

When customizing the ProductListComponentService default file, the SORT operation on the page does not work.

**How can I change the default number of products to be displayed on a page when paging.**

Is there a structure like infinite scrolling?
view: {
infiniteScroll: {
active: false,
productLimit: 500,
showMoreButton: false,
},
},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no configurations for listing yet. In order to change the number of results I did the following:

I extended `ProductListComponentService` and I was able to override the `defaultPageSize` property to get 24 products. After doing that the sorting was still functional.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductListComponentService } from '@spartacus/storefront';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyProductListComponentService extends ProductListComponentService {
  defaultPageSize = 24;
}
```

In my app.module.ts:

```
[...]
providers: [{ provide: ProductListComponentService, useClass: MyProductListComponentService }],
```